Vaadin 24 scrolling - possible bug in platform or sanity check needed
I just cannot get scrolling to work properly with the Vaadin 24 framework.
This code:
public class Test2View extends Dialog {

    public Test2View() {

        setHeaderTitle("Test");
        setResizable(true);
        setWidth("800px");
        setHeight("600px");

        VerticalLayout content = new VerticalLayout();
        content.setPadding(false);
        content.setHeightFull();
        add(content);

        content.add(new TextField("Name"));

        TabSheet tabSheet = new TabSheet();
        tabSheet.addClassName(LumoUtility.Overflow.HIDDEN);
        tabSheet.setSizeFull();
        content.add(tabSheet);

        tabSheet.add("Instructions", createViewLayout());
    }

    private VerticalLayout createViewLayout() {

        VerticalLayout previewLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        previewLayout.addClassNames(LumoUtility.Border.ALL, LumoUtility.BorderColor.CONTRAST_20);
        previewLayout.setHeightFull();

        VerticalLayout phaseLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        phaseLayout.addClassNames(LumoUtility.Border.ALL, LumoUtility.BorderColor.CONTRAST_20);
        phaseLayout.add(new Span("Phase"));

        VerticalLayout instructionLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        instructionLayout.addClassNames(LumoUtility.Border.ALL, LumoUtility.BorderColor.CONTRAST_20);
        instructionLayout.setHeightFull();

        VerticalLayout scrollLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        scrollLayout.setHeightFull();

        Scroller scroller = new Scroller(scrollLayout, Scroller.ScrollDirection.BOTH);
        scroller.setSizeFull();
        instructionLayout.add(new Span("Inputs"), scroller);

        previewLayout.add(phaseLayout, instructionLayout);

        IntStream.range(0, 20).forEach(i -> {
            TextField textField = new TextField("Text " + i);
            scrollLayout.add(textField);
        });

        return previewLayout;
    }
}

Called using:
new Test2View().open();

Produces the following:
screen shot
I’ve been on this for 3 days now and still can’t find a solution, and I’m questioning my sanity. Surely it can’t be this hard to produce what I require - just a simple vertical scroll within the input layout with no overflow and therefore no superfluous scroll bars appearing for the overflown content. Note if the “phaseLayout” is removed, then all is good. Please help as this is holding me up a big time with Vaadin.

What are you trying to achieve by nesting 5 levels of containers (previewLayout -> phaseLayout -> instructionLayout -> Scroller -> scrollLayout)?

This is just some test code that mimics a more complex layout scenario where the nested containers do in fact contain other components. You're not getting the benefit of seeing that in this code so it looks as though the nesting is superfluous. Also phaseLayout and instructionLayout are not in fact nested but are siblings, and Scroller is a necessary Vaadin container for scrolling content (in scrollLayout). My real world code in fact splits these tasks over different classes that are invoked dynamically as needed. Hope this clarifies it a bit.

Okay, thanks to posting on StackOverflow I found a related answer on this page.
It works if I add:
instructionLayout.setHeight("1px");
previewLayout.expand(instructionLayout);

Not exactly intuitive but a solution nonetheless.
